# How to deploy jsp file in tomcate created in the "android test project"

Tags: java, android, tomcat, web, automation

I have created the "Android test Project". I have put android test case file and some java file of different applications and some jsp/servlet files. What i want, I want to run the index.jsp in which i have option for run the android application or the another java application or  the web application.

I am able to run the standalone java application and android application but not able to run the web application because it is not deployed on the tomcat. I not getting the option for "Run as server" or the any option for deploying this application on tomcat in eclipse juno

Could any one help me out how i can deployed this application on the tomcat so that my web based application start running. it will work well when i created the web based project instead of android based.

I think some configuration is required for run jsp on server from android based project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the project to the server , if deployment to the added Server in the Eclipse is what you need !

Answer (score 0):

export ur java web application as a "WAR" file..

Copy that inside webapp directory of apache...and in browser type... localhost/[UR war file name]/index.jsp..

Hope it helps...